# How to use generics in a java method

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble adding generics to a piece of code that I'm working on, I've searched around and none of the examples I've seen so far quite capture what I've trying to do so I'm reaching out for help.

Currently I have this code which processes a list of `UserDTO` objects that have only their ID's populated and gets the full details of each `User` from a restful web-service:

```
//userIds  and userDetails declared previously
for (UserDTO user : userIds) {
    UserDTO populatedUser = webResource.path(REST_USER_PATH).path(user.getId().
        toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class).
            getEntity(UserDTO.class);

    userDetails.add(populatedUser);
}
```

Now this is going to be a pattern for the piece of work I'm currently undertaking, I'll need to be able to convert lists of `DTO` objects which have just the Id's populated, to lists of fully populated `DTO` objects by calling a web service. What I'd like to do is create a generic method to let me do this.

All the different `DTO` objects that I need to do this for extend our `BaseDTO` so I came up with the following, unfortunately it does not compile but hopefully it will show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
  public <T extends BaseDTO> getListOfPopulatedDTOs(
      List <T extends BaseDTO> unpopulatedDTOs, String restPath) {

      List<BaseDTO> populatedDTOs = new ArrayList<BaseDTO>();

      for (BaseDTO unpopulatedDTO : unpopulatedDTOs) {
          BaseDTO populatedDTO = webResource.path(restPath).path(
              unpopulatedDTO.getId().toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
                  get(ClientResponse.class).getEntity(T.class);

          populatedDTOs.add(populatedDTO);
      }

      return populatedDTOs;
  }
```

Any help or advice would be gratefully received. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the compilation errors?

Comment: I am learning to - so question - if he wants a generic method - how do you get rid of the 'ClientResponse.class' which is hard-coded in the method, right? Don't you need some type of clazz or something to be more generic, or is ClientResponse a 'base' class for the response data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give the bounds again in the formal parameter. And also `T.class` is not valid. You've to pass the `Class<T>` explicitly to the method. You can change your method to something like this:

```
public <T extends BaseDTO> List<T> populateDTOList(List<T> unpopulatedDTOs, Class<T> clazz, String restPath) {
    List<T> populatedDTOs = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T unpopulatedDTO : unpopulatedDTOs) {
        T populatedDTO = webResource.path(restPath)
                            .path(unpopulatedDTO.getId().toString())
                            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                            .get(ClientResponse.class)
                            .getEntity(clazz);

        populatedDTOs.add(populatedDTO);
    }

    return populatedDTOs;
}
```

Just make sure you have the `getId()` method declared in type `BaseDTO`, else you won't be able to access it.

Also, you're missing the return type of the method. I've put it here. And the method is better named as `populateDTOList`.

Comment: I am learning to - so question - if he wants a generic method - how do you get rid of the 'ClientResponse.class' which is hard-coded in the method, right?  Don't you need some type of clazz or something to be more generic, or is ClientResponse a 'base' class for the response data?

Comment: @mikemil Good question. You should post it on the question itself, so that we can get answer from OP.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply, I'm must grateful for a speedy response. Rohit's answer seems most complete but I am having problems calling the method. I will post additional info in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I solved my compile error, I was just calling with the wrong parameters! Rohit's answer is correct! Thanks again all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare type information only one time.In a generic method,you do this before teh return type,not in the parameter itself.Just change it to this :-

```
 public <T extends BaseDTO> getListOfPopulatedDTOs(List <T> unpopulatedDTOs, String restPath) {
List<BaseDTO> populatedDTOs = new ArrayList<BaseDTO>();

for (BaseDTO unpopulatedDTO : unpopulatedDTOs) {
  BaseDTO populatedDTO = webResource.path(restPath).path(unpopulatedDTO.getId().toString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
      .get(ClientResponse.class).getEntity(T.class);

  populatedDTOs.add(populatedDTO);
}

return populatedDTOs;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generics** are only compile time checks. So you can't do `T.class` because T and all other generic information gets removed during compiling.

Your interface could be something like:

```
public <T extends BaseDTO> List<T> getListOfPopulatedDTOs(List <T> unpopulatedDTOs, String restPath)
```

And you can do `getEntity(unpopulatedDTOs.get(0).getClass())`  (check that the list is not null or 0 size)